# Equivalence of euclidean and analytic geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I read about the axioms of euclidean geometry.

**How is analytic geometry rigorously defined? What are the axioms?** And most important: How to prove that all the results proved in analytic geometry are **indeed the same things** as euclidean geometry? How to show that they are equivalent? For example: How to show that $y=x$ is indeed a line and not a curve?

Comment: you may have enough background to read Hartshorne's book Geometry: Euclid and Beyond  which does, or summarizes, work by Pejas and Bachmann on classifying Hilbert planes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Analytic geometry is not generally axiomatized in the way you seem to be asking.

Instead, one proceeds as follows. First, the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ are axiomatized, as you learn in any advanced calculus or real analysis course. Second, the Euclidean plane $\mathbb{E}^2$ is **defined** as the Cartesian product $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, and lines are **defined** as solution sets of linear equations $ax+by=c$, and angles are **defined** using the law of cosines, and so one… Third, once all the basic concepts of Euclidean geometry are defined, the axioms of Euclidean geometry are **proved** as theorems.

You can see this procedure carried out in several modern geometry textbooks, for example Hartshorne's book "Geometry: Euclid and Beyond".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but isn't the law of cosines a theorem from euclidean geometry?

Comment: What I mean is that given two rays $AB$ and $AC$, the angle $\theta \in [0,\pi]$ between them may be defined by the formula $$\theta = \frac{\cos^{-1}\left(|AB|^2 + |AC|^2 - |BC|^2\right)}{2 \times |AB| \times |AC|}$$

Comment: ok, so one takes the law of cosines, which was proved from the axioms of euclidean geometry, as a pure definition of angle in order to prove the axioms of euclidean geometry?

Comment: @user50224: That's one way to put it, but I would put it differently. One takes one's mathematical knowledge, and one uses it to construct an analytic model for Euclidean Geometry, under which the law of cosines is subverted for the purpose of defining angle. Notice, in buliding up Euclidean geometry analytically, I am avoiding any assumption that the law of cosines is *known to be true*, which only makes sense if angle is *already defined*. Instead, I am using the law of cosines, appropriately solved for $\theta$, as the formula for *defining* angle in analytic geometry.